# c++ mutex member of class causing compilation Error

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory, mutex

I'm not sure why this is happening when I add a mutex member to myClass(in this example mu):

```
Error   C2661   "'std::tuple<
void (__thiscall MyNameSpace::myClass::* )(void),MyNameSpace::myClass>::tuple': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments include\memory 2438
```

```
namespace MyNameSpace{
class myClass{
    shared_ptr<myClass2> property;
    mutex mu;

public:
    myClass(shared_ptr<myClass2> arg):property(std::move(arg)) {

    }
     void Run(){
         ...........
         }
}
class myClass2{
public:
    myClass2(std::string str) {
        trace(str);
    }

}
       }
int main(){
shared_ptr<myClass2> new_obj(new myClass2("somthing"));
    thread(&myClass::Run, myClass(new_obj)).join();
.......other stuff.....
}
```

and How can i overcome this?

Comment: "memory error" suggests that it's a runtime error where you've corrupted data.  Which isn't what you've done.  In any case; perhaps you should post the whole error message rather than just a small part of it?  I don't know if my line 2438 is the same as yours

Comment: Please share a minimal, reproductible example if you want us to help

Comment: @Ron its the name of the member of myClass

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: `thread(&myClass::Run, myClass(new_obj)).join();`  I think this line deserves much more attention - it's UB (what object is your thread running on once it's created the thread object?) mixed with a bad concept (why create a thread if you're just going to join on it?)

Comment: @UKMonkey Is it really UB?  `join` will block until the thread ends and it is all one expression.

Comment: @NathanOliver hmm, you're right; for some reason I had in my mind that the `.join()` was another expression - though the moment the join is moved further down it will be!

Answer (score 2):

It is a compilation error, not a memory error.

Note that `std::mutex` is not copiable. So, the class containing it becomes non-copiable as well.

I *guess* (as you do not show the relevant code) that you attempt to copy an instance of `myClass`, and that causes the above compilation error.

In particular, you can search places in your code, where you pass or return `myClass` instances by value.

**UPDATE**: As pointed out by @NathanOliver, such a place in the above snippet is:

```
thread(&myClass::Run, myClass(new_obj))
```

where a temporary `myClass` is created.

Comment: no there is no attempt to copy an instance of myClass in my code

Comment: @Amir Rasti ...or maybe you're just unaware of such an attempt.

Comment: @AmirRasti Yes there is, `thread(&myClass::Run, myClass(new_obj))`

Comment: @IgorR. Huh?  `myClass(new_obj)` creates a temporary `myClass`.  the constructor for `std::thread` copies that into the threads storage

Comment: @NathanOliver ah, sure :)

Comment: if so then how can i overcome this?

Comment: @Amir Rasti make sure your `myClass` has move-constructor (either compiler-generated or custom), then `myClass(new_obj)` will be moved rather than copied.

Comment: @IgorR. That won't work.  `std::mutex` is not copyable or moveable so `myClass` will be as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, std::mutex is not movable, what a pity... Amir Rasti so try using pImpl idiom or just store the mutex by (smart)pointer, if it's appropriate in your design.